# how to remove everything before second last dot in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function that removes everything before the second to last dot. If the string is something like `www.dev.community.google.com` then I want to remove everything before `google.com`.

These sub domains aren't always alike, sometimes they will just be `www.google.com` and sometimes `www.community.google.com`.

So the point is to remove everything before and including the second to last dot. How can I do this with php?

Comment: Check my post. It will work for all types of URL.

Comment: Improving grammar and prasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution will work for all kinds of url:

```
<?php

function getDomain($url)
{
    $exp = explode('.', $url);
    $count = count($exp);
    $tmp_arr[0] = $exp[$count-2];
    $tmp_arr[1] = $exp[$count-1];
    $final_str = implode('.', $tmp_arr);
    return $final_str;
}

$url = 'www.dev.community.google.com';
echo getDomain($url);

echo '<br/>';

$url = 'www.community.com';
echo getDomain($url);
?>
```

> Output
>
> google.com
>
> community.com

Here is the working demo [link](https://eval.in/508005).

Comment: Np. Have created a function for re-usability ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a handful of different solutions.

One of the smallest:

```
function domain($input)
{
    // Split the input string into pieces, use dot (.) as delimiter
    $pieces = explode('.', $input);
    // Get the last two pieces
    $domain = array_slice($pieces, -2);
    // Join them back using dot as delimiter and return
    return implode('.', $domain);
}

echo(domain('www.dev.community.google.com')."\n");
echo(domain('www.community.google.com')."\n");
echo(domain('community.google.com')."\n");
echo(domain('google.com')."\n");
echo(domain('com')."\n");
```

The output is:

```
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
com
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `addhttp()` and `get_domain()` functions and use them like this:

```
<?php

print get_domain("www.dev.community.google.com");

function get_domain($url)
{
  $url = addhttp($url);
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

**Output**

```
google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that uses `regexp` to identify and keep only the last two components:

```
function domain($input)
{
    return preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]*\.[^.]*)$/', '\1', $input);
}
```

The regular expression is nothing special:

```
^                  # matches the start of the string
.*                 # anything, any number of times
\.                 # followed by a dot (need to escape it to get its literal value)
(                  # followed by a group that contains:
  [^.]*            #   anything but a dot, any number of times
  \.               #   a dot
  [^.]*            #   anything but a dot, any number of times
)                  # this is where the group closes; it it used to capture its content
$                  # the end of the string (nothing else is allowed after the group)
```

The replace string (`\1`) contains a [back reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) to that part of the input string that matches the first group from the `regexp`. The one and only group in the `regexp` matches the last two components of the domain, joined by the dot.

**Remark**

If the input string does not contain any dot then it has only one component. In this case the `regexp` doesn't match and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) returns the input string unaltered (which is what we also expect from it in this situation).